# Cant find @Named CDI bean with default name in EL/Facelet

Tags: jsf-2, el, cdi

In the [jee6 tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbak.html) i can read the following:

> The @Named qualifier allows you to access the bean by
>   using the bean name, with the first letter in lowercase. For example,
>   a Facelets page would refer to the bean as printer.
>
> You can specify an argument to the @Named qualifier to use a
>   nondefault name:

However when i try to use @Named without adding an argument, My bean can not be found and i get exception like below.

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class MTestBean {
...
}
```

Exception;

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: /MyPage.xhtml @15,65 listener="#{mTestBean.init}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'mTestBean' resolved to null
```

But if i use

```
@Named("mTestBean")
```

Everything works fine. Is this expected behaviour? Is there a way i can list what beans are available in EL, maybe im assuming wrong default name?

Comment: Are you using JSF 2.0 or JSF 2.2? `@Named` and `@ViewScoped` can't be used together unless it's JSF 2.2.

Comment: In using isf 2.2 but the scope of my bean is not relevant for the question afaik

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You actually have to reference the bean using #{MTestBean.xxx}.  Interestingly, NetBeans makes the same assumption regarding the default name and will autocomplete with #{mTestBean.xxx}.  As BalusC pointed out, this naming behavior does follow the JavaBeans spec.  From section 8.8 -

> ...to support the occasional use of all
>   upper-case names, we check **if the first two characters of the name are both upper case and if
>   so leave it alone**. So for example,
>   “FooBah” becomes “fooBah”
>   “Z” becomes “z”
>   “URL” becomes “URL”
>   We provide a method Introspector.decapitalize which implements this conversion rule.

As far as listing the available beans with CDI, your best bet is the javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager.  See this [link](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/how_to_discover_all_deployed)

EDIT: Here is a version slightly modified from the link to display the EL name, not just the class.

```
public void listAllBeans() throws NamingException{
        //Get the BeanManager
        InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext();
        BeanManager bm = (BeanManager) initialContext.lookup("java:comp/BeanManager");

        //List all CDI Managed Beans and their EL-accessible name
        Set<Bean<?>> beans = bm.getBeans(Object.class,new AnnotationLiteral<Any>() {});
        for (Bean<?> bean : beans) {
            System.out.println(bean.getBeanClass().getName() + " / bean name = " + bean.getName());
        }
    }
```

And the output for our test bean -

> com.xxx.jsf.beans.MTestBean / bean name = MTestBean

Comment: This is absolutely not a problem/bug. The behavior is just fully specified in Javabeans specification. If you link and cite the relevant section, you get an upvote.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I guess the only problem is the IDE making the same false assumption.

Comment: Great this explains it. Just annoying the default name differs between cdi and jsf-beans

Comment: The ide prop. Assumes jsf-beans

Comment: @AkselWillgert Good point.  I didn't realize JSF @ ManagedBean would generate "mTestBean" but a quick test proved it.  I thought that JSF and CDI were implementing the same basic spec regarding mbeans.